# Unable to set the default value of a string variable to DBNull

Tags: .net, vb.net

My understanding is that the datatype `String`in VB.NET is nullable.

Therefore, I don't understand why the following code returns the error "Value of DBNull Cannot Be Converted To String"

`Public name As String = DBNull.Value`

For context, I have a class whose values will be written to a database. When the class's object is created, it is possible that not all its variables will have values. I want missing values to be `null` in the database, so therefore I intended to set the variables' default value to DBNull as above. But this isn't working due to the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DBNull` is not really equivalent to `Nothing`. It is a class. `Value` is a `shared` field of the `DBNull` object, which just sets the value of `Value` to an instance of the `DBNull` class. You can see this for yourself [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/dbnull.cs,28).

Comment: To "convert" `DBNull` to a string you need to use `DBNull.Value.ToString`, Since you have to test for `DBNull` in order to determine if it needs to be converted to a string, what is the difference between doing that and replacing it with `Nothing` when saving it to a string?

Answer (score 0):

`DBNull` can't be converted to a string, you need to test for it. You can assign `Nothing` to a string, so you can use:

```vb
    Public name As String = Nothing
```

Comment: The link provided by @Icemanind shows a .ToString() method that returns String.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want with the writes to the database, you can use `Nothing` for the value and then, when writing to the database, check for `yourString Is Nothing` and if so then set the parameter's value to `DBNull.Value`.

```
Public Class Datum
    Property Name As String = Nothing
End Class

Sub X()
    Dim q As New Datum

    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
        ' other code...

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Name", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Size = 123})
        If q.Name Is Nothing Then
            cmd.Parameters("@Name").Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters("@Name").Value = q.Name
        End If

        ' other code....
    End Using

End Sub
```

N.B. For correct operation, use the `Is` and `IsNot` operators when checking for `Nothing`, do not use the `=` operator.